# Remove Duplicates from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

How to remove duplicates from the below xml using xslt. Below is the code am using. It works fine for removing the duplicates but am not able to add the corresponding values

```
    <schedules>
       <flight>
      <Flight>
      <fno>122</fno>
      <acode>aa</acode>
        <Dest1IATA>ATL</Dest1IATA>  
        <Dest1desc>Atlanta Airport</Dest1desc>
        <Dest1town>Atlanta </Dest1town>
        <Dest2IATA>JFK</Dest2IATA>           
        <Dest2desc></Dest2desc>
        <Dest2town></Dest2town>
        <Dest2cntry></Dest2cntry>            
        <Dest3IATA>LGA</Dest3IATA>           
        <Dest3desc></Dest3desc>
        <Dest3town></Dest3town>
        <Dest3cntry></Dest3cntry>
        </Flight>
          <Flight>
      <fno>124</fno>
      <acode>aB</acode>
        <Dest1IATA>LCY</Dest1IATA>  
        <Dest1desc>LCY Airport</Dest1desc>
        <Dest1town>LCY</Dest1town>
        <Dest2IATA>DXB</Dest2IATA>           
        <Dest2desc></Dest2desc>
        <Dest2town></Dest2town>
        <Dest2cntry></Dest2cntry>            
        <Dest3IATA>LGA</Dest3IATA>           
        <Dest3desc></Dest3desc>
        <Dest3town></Dest3town>
        <Dest3cntry></Dest3cntry>
        </Flight>         
        </flight>
        </schedules>
```

Xslt code:

```
     <xsl:for-each select="(//schedules/flight/Flight/Dest1IATA | //schedules/flight/Flight/Dest2IATA | //schedules/flight/Flight/Dest3IATA)[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('Keycity', .))]">
      <xsl:sort select="//schedules/flight/Flight/Dest1IATA | //schedules/flight/Flight/Dest2IATA | //schedules/flight/Flight/Dest3IATA"/>

      <!--<xsl:value-of select="." />-->
      <xsl:if test="local-name() = 'Dest1IATA'  and //schedules/flight/Flight/Dest1IATA != ''">
        <Row Action="ADD">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />|<xsl:value-of select="//schedules/flight/Flight/Dest1desc" />|<xsl:value-of  select="//schedules/flight/Flight/Dest1town" />|<xsl:value-of  select="//schedules/flight/Flight/Dest1cntry" />
        </Row>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="local-name() = 'Dest2IATA'  and //schedules/flight/Flight/Dest2IATA != ''">
        <Row Action="ADD">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />|<xsl:value-of select="//schedules/flight/Flight/Dest2desc" />|<xsl:value-of  select="//schedules/flight/Flight/Dest2town" />|<xsl:value-of  select="//schedules/flight/Flight/Dest2cntry" />
        </Row>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="local-name() = 'Dest3IATA'  and //schedules/flight/Flight/Dest3IATA != ''">
        <Row Action="ADD">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />|<xsl:value-of select="//schedules/flight/Flight/Dest3desc" />|<xsl:value-of  select="//schedules/flight/Flight/Dest3town" />|<xsl:value-of  select="//schedules/flight/Flight/Dest3cntry" />
        </Row>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

ExpectedOutput should be

```
ROW|Add|ATL|Atlanta Airport|
ROW|Add|JFK||
ROW|Add|LGA||
ROW|Add|LCY|LCYAirport|LCY
ROW|Add|DXB||
```

Output with above Code

```
ROW|Add|ATL||
ROW|Add|JFK||
ROW|Add|LGA||
ROW|Add|LCY||
ROW|Add|DXB||
```

Comment: You need to explain what are "the corresponding values". -- P.S. When I suggested you should close [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362143/how-to-remove-duplicates-when-using-xslt), I did not mean you should delete it.

Comment: Sorry i did not see an option to close it. Corresponding values are Country,town and description for that destination

Comment: You close a question by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet produces an output quite similar to what you expect. It could be a lucky guess or just a coincidence.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="dest" match="Dest1IATA | Dest2IATA | Dest3IATA" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/schedules">
    <xsl:for-each select="(flight/Flight/Dest1IATA | flight/Flight/Dest2IATA | flight/Flight/Dest3IATA)[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('dest', .))]">
        <xsl:text>ROW|Add|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="self::Dest1IATA">
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../Dest1desc" />
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../Dest1town" />      
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
ROW|Add|ATL|Atlanta Airport|Atlanta 
ROW|Add|JFK
ROW|Add|LGA
ROW|Add|LCY|LCY Airport|LCY
ROW|Add|DXB
```